# Xamarin build fails - GenerateGitReleaseNotesTask failure

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been struggaling with this issue whole day today where my Xamarin app (Android) build fails with the following error.

This issue in github did not help https://github.com/dansiegel/Mobile.BuildTools/issues/161.
Anyone who has seen the same issue and has a fix? Let me know please.

I am building this on Visual Studio 2020 on a Windows 11 Home edition.

[image]

Comment: Have you try repair your vs?